# Duplicate tabs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to duplicate tab with javascript to have all history of the previous tab, I known I can open a new tab with window but it seems there is not way to duplicate the current tab with all its history. Any help would be appreciate

Comment: Plead edit question to indicate "browser tab"

Comment: You cant. Imagen a website is able to duplicate random tabs... The only possible way could be a web-extension/add-on